# Second SKU doesn't recognize -Google In App Billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i use code from following link to add In App Billing to my app and am successful on adding it.However when i use second SKU for consumable item it doesn't recognize.Can anyone tell me how to add multiple sku to the following code from this site https://www.gaffga.de/implementing-in-app-billing-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

you need to change package of application, upload APK to draft on Google Play publisher account, replace SKU with new one, then it will work -- cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply.can you add a sample code for that if possible referring to above link?

Comment: This is what i did.i globally declared new SKU with same test package and added new SKU to second buy button and on Consume i did an if - else condition ie if(purchase.getsku() so an so.but it just gave me first sku value and not second one

Comment: Govind, pls change your application package, it would be done by refactoring, then you will able to upload the apk on your own developer account as a draft. the SKU should relate to the Application on your developer account.

Comment: Previously added SKU (Which is working) is added to the Google play from the developer account where Application is uploaded. That application can't recognize your own SKU which is not related to the same application draft

Comment: Ok.Thank you will try and let you know ;)

Comment: I tried.Could purchase successfully,but when i consume it doesn't consume properly